# mitmproxy not showing traffic for android app

Tags: mitmproxy

I want to sniff an app traffic to discover the end points of its api. So I'm using mitmproxy. In the beggining the app didn't work (it wasn't able to connect to server) when I was sniffing. After rearching I was able to solve it (I think it was due to certificate pinning). Now evertyhing is suppossed to be working fine, I can see traffic of any app on the phone. However the app I want to analyze is not showing in the logs, nothing at all despite it is working properly on the phone.

What am I doing wrong? Isn't the app using an http protocol?

Thank you.

Comment: I assume you have configured mitmproxy as proxy in the Android Wifi configuration? In that set-up the app may ignore the proxy settings e.g. because it uses it's own HTTP client implementation that is not aware of the proxy settings. Hence the app works as it bypasses mitmproxy.

Comment: Yest, it is configured in the Android Wifi configuration. So is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Use mitmproxy in transparent mode instead. Then you have full control over all connections. This requires to have a Linux system that gets all the traffic by default (e.,g. by opening up an software hotspot on Linux).

Comment: On Android 13 emulator with playstore, i am facing a totally different issue.
All apps and chrome works like there's no proxy at all. mit proxy sees no connections. However connections attempts from android studio are detected.


AVD is configured to use proxy settings from android studio

Answer (score 1):

From working on a similar project myself for some time I assume your initial problem was not due to certificate pinning but from [Android Nougat or higher not allowing the use of custom certificates for apps](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/07/changes-to-trusted-certificate.html). Since you seem to have solved this issue, there will still be some traffic you can not capture and **this** is due to certificate pinning. The app you want to analyze might be configured to not trust the mitmproxy certificate rendering your sniffing attempt useless.

Comment: Is there a solution to byass certificate pinning? Thanks so much

Comment: Depends on the application. [This post](https://www.nccgroup.com/uk/about-us/newsroom-and-events/blogs/2017/november/bypassing-androids-network-security-configuration/) might shine some light on the issue. Never tried it myself, though.

Comment: @Lucas, you can try to bypass certificate pinning by patching the application with a tool that disables these settings, for example - [apk-mitm](https://github.com/shroudedcode/apk-mitm).

I've tried it, and in my case all it took was *one command from terminal*. I had more trouble installing it than using it