# How to sniff network traffic from a mobile app that uses it's own HTTP Client? Is Charles enough?

Tags: android, httpclient, charles-proxy, frida, rooted-device

Over the past few days, i've encountered several problems upon trying to sniff some network from an android application.

What i've done so far:

~Rooted my device
~Installed a frida-server
~Succesfully performed my frida-script
~Installed Charles CA on my phone
~Proxied my Wi-fi to Charles in order to capture all network requests

**Describing the problem:**
The app works perfect with and without the pinning bypass (still connected to charles), all my mobile requests go through, can navigate quite easy within the app. But Charles isn't detecting any network traffic which is really weird.

After doing some googling, I found that it happens due to the fact that the app uses it's own HTTP Client implementation, which therefore Charles doesn't recognize by default.

**I tried:**

~Activating Transparent HTTP proxying
~Using SOCKs proxying
~Using different ports for Charles.

None of the above seemed to work.

**I'm looking for a way to sniff every single request that goes out of my phone, so therefore, i can sniff these requests too. Does Charles fit for that? Do i have to use another tool?**

Comment: You can try to sniff all traffic in pcap format and see it in Wireshark e.g. using this app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.egorovandreyrm.pcapremote Then you will see if the uses TCP traffic at all. May be it just ignores the system proxy settings. Have you tried to place the device in a network where internet is only reachable through the proxy?

Comment: Do i have to bypass pinning with this app? I haven't tried to put the device in a network as you described, don't know how to perform that action!

Comment: Does the app works if you force it to use Charles (with or without HTTPS interception)? If it works when you disable HTTPS interception then you have an app that uses cert pinning. Finally: How to disable an unknown http client - who knows, that depends on the client. Is it implemented in java or as .so library. You first need to reverse engineer it, identify the relevant methods and then develop a bypass.

Comment: The app works the just same with my charles proxying and without it, this is what makes me believe it doesn't care at all about my CA and my whole cert pinning

Comment: I came with the ideea that it uses an unknown http client by accessing this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61710190/mitmproxy-not-showing-traffic-for-android-app

Comment: @Robert do you think that creating a socks tunnel will impose the app to log the traffic on my charles?

PS: I tried creating a SOCKS tunnel using SocksDroid and i couldn't navigate anymore within the app because it said i was not connected to the internet. Maybe i didn't configure the socks tunnel as i should. Other apps were working tho. Haven't tested on all of them!
Do you think that such behaviour should be because the app refuses to use my proxy but still performs http requests?

Comment: First use Wireshark to see if the app uses TCP at all. If it does note the ports I would use mitmproxy in transparent mode. A network correctly configured to be monitored by mitmproxy in transparent mode (vi iptables) should be the best option in my opinion.